# How to track arbitrary object picked by mouse using YOLO?

Tags: yolo, object-tracking

We can track human, car, animal, etc using YOLO V8.
In order to track object, the model has to be trained on target objects.

But I have to track arbitrary objects picked by mouse on a video.
Since the target object is unknown, I can't train YOLO model.

I thought that it's possible to track arbitrary object by comparing feature map calculated by pretrained YOLO model.
i.e.

1. In a frame, choose a pixel and save an image that contains the pixel.
2. Calculate feature map of the image using pretrained YOLO model.
3. In the next frame, find best matching candidate with above feature map.

I think this is possible, but not sure it's correct.
And if possible, how can I implement this?